# Angular Transclusion/jQuery Not Working with Karma + Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, webpack

I have recently converted a project I am working on over to `webpack`, including my unit tests for the `Angular` front-end. I have some unit tests written for some directives with custom transclusion functionality in the `link` functions which passes in a `webpack`-less testing environment, yet when tested with `karma-webpack` they do not pass. Allow me to demonstrate:

Standard *karma.conf.js*

```
// Reference: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: './',


    files : [

        'public/tests.bundle.js'
    ],


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {

        'public/tests.bundle.js' : ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },


    // . . .


    webpack: {

        // Just do inline source maps instead of the default
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',

        module: { 

            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
            ],
        }
    }
  });
};
```

Test bundle

```
import 'jquery';

import 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks/angular-mocks';

var testsContext = require.context('.', true, /.+\.spec\.js$/);

testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext);
```

Angular Directive in ES6

```
import directiveFactory from '../../directivefactory.js';

// ## Directive Definition
class pageHeader {

    constructor() {

        this.template =
        `
            <div class="d5-page-header-wrapper">

                <div class="d5-page-header">

                    <!-- Main page header text -->
                    <!-- component user content insertion point 1 -->
                    <span class="text-main" transclude-id="header"></span>

                    <!-- Small page header text -->
                    <!-- component user content insertion point 2 -->
                    <span class="text-small" transclude-id="small"></span>

                    <hr class="break">

                    <!-- Page header text lead -->
                    <!-- component user content insertion point 3 -->
                    <span class="text-lead" transclude-id="lead"></span>

                    <!-- Custom navigation button -->
                    <button class="btn btn-custom btn-block btn-lg">

                        Jump to Collections <span class="glyphicon
                            glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>

                    </button>

                </div>

            </div>
        `;
        this.restrict = 'E';
        this.scope = {};
        this.bindToController = {

        };
        this.transclude = true;
        this.controller = PageHeaderController;
        this.controllerAs = 'vm';
    }

    // ###Optional Link Function
    link (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

        transclude ((clone) => {

            angular.forEach(clone, (cloneEl, value) => {

                // If the clone element has attributes...
                if(cloneEl.attributes) {

                    // Get desired target ID...
                    var tId = cloneEl.attributes["transclude-to"].value;

                    // Find target element with that ID...
                    var target = elem.find('[transclude-id="' + tId + '"]');

                    // Append element to target
                    target.append(cloneEl);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

export default ['pageHeader', directiveFactory(pageHeader)];
```

Unit Test

```
describe('page header directive', () => {

    let elem, scope;

    // Mock our page-header directive
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(pageHeader));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(($rootScope, $compile) => {

        // Define the directive markup to test with
        elem = angular.element(
            `
            <div>

                <page-header>

                    <span transclude-to="header">

                        Test Header

                    </span>

                    <span transclude-to="small">

                        Test Small Header

                    </span>

                    <span transclude-to="lead">

                        Test Lead Content

                    </span>

                </page-header>

            </div>
            `
        );

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $compile(elem)(scope);

        scope.$digest();
    }));

    describe('link transclusion function', () => {

        it("should create a main header element containing the component " +
            "user's markup", () => {

            let items = elem.find('.text-main');

            console.log(items);

            // FAIL
            expect(items.eq(0).text()).toContain('Test Header');
        });
    });
});
```

I am not quite sure exactly where the problem lies, but it seems the problem lies in my implementation or `karma-webpack` as the code works in the browser as it should. In any case, I'd appreciate the help with the matter.

#### EDIT

Everything with jQuery appears to be working fine.

Inspecting the elements to see if the content was transcluded or not also reveals that the content did not get transcluded as the tags that should contain transcluded content are empty in the console.